# Create new columns from an existing column conditionally

Tags: r

I am trying to conditionally generate values from a columns of data, conditionally based on the value in one of the columns.

```
fio2 <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.8)
pao2 <- c(100, 60, 90)
paco2 <- c(35, 45, 45)
df <- data.frame(fio2, pao2, paco2)
```

If fio2 < 0.5 I would like the corresponding value of pao2 in the same row to be copied into a new column (pao2_raw). If fio2 >= 0.5 I would like to perform a function that uses other values in the row, then store it in a new column (aao2). In my actual data there are many data points, and the relevant columns are dispersed through the data set. My thinking is as follows:

```
#Function for when fio2 >= 0.5
aagrad <- function(x) {
(x * (705) - df$paco2/0.8) - df$pao2
}  
#Sorting function
aasort <- function(x) {
  if (x < 0.5) {
    df$pao2_raw <- df$pao2
  } else {
    aao2 <- aagrad(x)
  }
}
#run function
sapply(df$fio2, aasort(df$fio2))
```

The expected output would be a df$pao2_raw with values of (100, NA, NA) - directly moved from $pao2, and df$aao2 (NA, 236.25,417.75) which were calculated using the aagrad function.

I don't have a clue about how to fix the syntax of aasort, and I'm not at all confident about the use of sapply to actually apply the conditional manipulations to the whole of a column. And assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it could be done with regular assignments and [`ifelse`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html):

```
df$pao2_raw = ifelse(df$fio2 < 0.5, df$pao2, NA)
df$aao2     = ifelse(df$fio2 < 0.5, NA, aagrad(df$fio2))

df

#   fio2 pao2 paco2 pao2_raw   aao2
# 1 0.25  100    35      100     NA
# 2 0.50   60    45       NA 236.25
# 3 0.80   90    45       NA 417.75
```

Comment: Thank you, very straightforward.